# Wifi loosing connection but still shows connected ( rtl8723be)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

Sorry but I'm quite new to this.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason my Wifi keeps loosing connection but still shows as connected, I will only notice when webpages don't load. Seems to be anywhere between 5-30 minutes after I boot. Enabling/disabling does nothing to solve the problem. A full reboot will fix it but again will only last for a couple of minutes. IF i disconnect it will niot reconnect again unless I restart, tryng to create new wifi connection leads to a connection 32 error. Happens with all access points.

> 